# How can I configure different right for same document?

Tags: permissions, groups, folder, access-rights

I have 2 groups (IT & Quality) and I want IT group can't access to all folder & documents but Quality can. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a kind of step-by-step guide for a document library in SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

1. Go to your library and click on "Shared with"

[image]

2. Click on "Advanced"

[image]

3. Click on "Stop Inheriting Permissions"

[image]

4. Set your groups with the permisson levels of your choice

[image]

**Single Document Permissons:**

For a single document select the document first (1), then click in "Files" and then "Shared With". There you can manage the document permissons.

But keep in mind, that it could be very exhausting managaging a bunch of those documentpermissons. Also you could loose track of those permisson settings very fast.

[image]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to configure only one document and not an entire library?

Comment: updated my answer